# What happened to QGIS 2.x LTR?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-2, lizmap

I've been using QGIS 2.x LTR version for quite some time now (mostly for Lizmap webclient because 3.x didn't perform as well), but today as I wanted to install QGIS on another PC, I realized I couldn't find QGIS 2.X LTR on their website anymore.

Does anyone know, will the new QGIS 3.4.5 LTR replace the 2.X LTR version for ever, causing me to upgrade and test on a newer version? Or is this just a temporary decision?

Comment: Yes QGIS 3.4.5 LTR replaced the 2.X LTR. QGIS 3.4.5 LTR is the first LTR for QGIS 3 and QGIS 2.x is no longer supported.

Comment: surprise! To be fair the qgis project has released their roadmap in the website for long time now. https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html

Comment: If you find QGIS useful please see this recent post [March 5th 2019] https://twitter.com/underdarkGIS/status/1102891897729765376 for a call for donations (if you can).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not temporary. I know that people hate change, but that's the way it is. QGIS 3.4.5 replaced 2.18 as a LTR. You can find older versions here: http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/

Answer (score 5):

For Lizmap, they plan to release a version 3.3 soon to be compatible with QGIS Server 3. It seems they need to wait for the QGIS 3.4.6 bugfix release (March 22th according to the roadmap link above). It's true that Lizmap 3.2 is not fully compatible with QGIS 3.

You are welcome to give your feedback on the link below about Lizmap 3.3:
https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-web-client/issues/1075

Answer (score 3):

QGIS 2.18 was replaced by the first 3.x LTR-version but you can still download and install 2.18 with the OSGeo4W-installer. Just search for the term qgis218 in the installer.
[image]

Comment: The OSGeo4W installer may eventually no longer include QGIS 2.18 as an option. But you can still download older versions of QGIS for various platforms from the [osgeo repository](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/) :)

Comment: @Joseph: the package qgis218 was added recently to be able to still download the old LTR which has reached its EOL. As long as its available in the OSGeo4W-installer I would prefer this way to install QGIS 2.18